Can I run selenium-hub on Docker Ubuntu container? If yes how so?
We want to save money by reducing the number. of VMs used to execute the UI tests. We want to verify on different OS browser combinations.
One of the possible solutions we came up wuth is Docker, but I couldn't find a way to execute our tests in Docker so that it emulates as if we are running tests on a VM (Linux) browser combination.
Can this be achieved using Docker?
I tried spinning up a Ubuntu container and configuring it with Chrome and Selenium-Hub, but I am not sure how I can pass the hub URL into my code.
